# Une nuance entre « passer à l’acte » et « passer à l’action »

Tags: sens

> 1 : Elle a envoyé des menaces de mort avant de **passer à l’acte**.
>
> 2 : Quand est-ce qu’on **passe à l’action** ?

J m’interroge sur une nuance entre les deux. Ou est-ce qu’ils sont interchangeables ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ils sont parfois interchangeables car un passage à l'acte est aussi un passage à l'action, mais l'inverse est rarement vrai.

Dans les deux cas, on passe d'une situation d'attente à une situation où quelque chose se passe. Il y a en revanche des différences à la fois dans l'origine de la situation d'attente et le type d'action qui suit.

- Passage à l'action:

> L'attente est souvent due à des circonstances extérieures défavorables.
>
> S'applique à n'importe quel type d'action (sport, guerre, professionnelle, etc.). L'action est souvent collective.

- Passage à l'acte:

> L'attente est souvent due à une inhibition personnelle avec un fort contenu émotionnel.
>
> Il s'applique à un acte plutôt personnel et grave (démission, divorce, suicide, agression, vol, meurtre, etc.) ou perçu comme tel.

Une autre différence qui découle du choix du mot utilisé, une action à une durée alors qu'un acte est ponctuel.